# load data to db2 in a single row (cell)

Tags: db2

I need to load an entire file (contains only ASCII text), to the database (DB2 Express ed.). The table has only two columns (ID, TEXT). The ID column is PK, with auto generated data, whereas the text is CLOB(5): I have no idea about the input parameter 5, it was entered by default in the Data Studio.

Now I need to use the load utility to save a text file (contains 5 MB of data), in a single row, namely in the column TEXT. I do not want the text to be broken into different rows.

thanks for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you may want to redefine your table: `CLOB(5)` means you expect 5 bytes in the column, which is hardly enough for a 5 MB file. After that you can use the DB2 `IMPORT` or `LOAD` commands with the `lobsinfile` modifier.

Create a text file and place LOB Location Specifiers (LLS) for each file you want to import, one per line.

> LLS is a way to tell IMPORT where to find LOB data. It has this
>   format: `<file path>[.<offset>.<length>/]`, e.g.
>   `/tmp/lobsource.dta.0.100/` to indicate that the first 100 bytes of
>   the file `/tmp/lobsource.dta` should be loaded into the particular LOB
>   column. Notice also the trailing slash. If you want to import the
>   entire file, skip the `offset` and `length` part. LLSes are placed in
>   the input file instead of the actual data for each row and LOB column.

So, for example:

```
echo "/home/you/yourfile.txt" > /tmp/import.dat
```

Since you said the IDs will be generated in the input data, you don't need to enter them in the input file, just don't forget to use the appropriate command modifier: `identitymissing` or `generatedmissing`, depending on how the ID column is defined.

Now you can connect to the database and run the `IMPORT` command, e.g.

```
db2 "import from /tmp/import.dat of del 
     modified by lobsinfile identitymissing
     method p (1) 
     insert into yourtable (yourclobcolumn)"
```

I split the command onto multiple lines for readability, but you should type it on a single line.

> `method p (1)` means parse the input file and read the column in position 1.

[More info in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/t0004575.html?lang=en)

Comment: thanks for your reply! However this command does not work, I get the error "An unexpected token "modified" was found following ")"...."

Comment: Sorry, I swapped they keywords around unintentionally. See the updated. I also posted a link to the manual...